# Prove that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^{2k}-1}{n^{2k-1}}=n$

Tags: limits

How would one prove that:

$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^{2k}-1}{n^{2k-1}}=n?$$

I basically have no idea. L'Hospital seems not to work here. Any hints?

Comment: Why doesn't L'Hospital rule work?Also consider that for $n=1$ this is not correct.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{a-b}{c}=\frac ac-\frac bc$

Comment: What is $n$? Is it a natural number or real?

Comment: Natural number.

Comment: Just split the fraction in two parts, e.g. $$\frac{n^{2k}-1}{n^{2k-1}}=\frac{n^{2k}}{n^{2k-1}}-\frac{1}{n^{2k-1}}$$ and evaluate those individually.

Comment: Is $n\gt1$? Because otherwise if $n=0$ we have $\frac {-1}0\neq0$ and if $n=1$ we have $\frac01=0\neq1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $n^{-(2k-1)}$, this gives
$$ \frac{n-n^{-(2k-1)}}{1} $$
whose limit is easliy seen to be $\frac n1$, assuming that $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using L'Hospitals you get
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{n^{2k}-1}{n^{2k-1}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{n^{2k}\log n}{n^{2k-1}\log n}=n$$ This works if $n>1$

Answer (score 1):

With *equivalents*:

$n^{2k}-1\sim_{k\to\infty}n^{2k},\;$ hence $\enspace\dfrac{n^{2k}-1}{n^{2k-1}}\sim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{n^{2k}}{n^{2k-1}}=n$.

Comment: Can I write in this way: $n^{2k}-1=O(n^{2k})$ to denote that $n^{2k}\gg 1$ for large $k$?

Comment: @MightyPython: No, because for example $2-\frac1k$ is $O(n^{2k})$ too, but is _not_ $\gg 1$ ever.

Comment: @MightyPython: No. $n^{2k}-1=O(n^{2k})$ is true just because  $n^{2k}-1\le n^{2k} $. Does it imply $n^{2k}\gg 1$? We really need equivalents to determine the limit.